# Having trouble with Rails Tutorial 9.6.5, can't get tests to pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

**Updated but still doesn't work!**

**update - I thought I had included the Rspec tests I was using but I had not. they are now included**

**I made the suggested change, but it still doesn't pass. The only hint given by the returned failed test is that it's just not achieving the goal of the test. It doesn't seem to give any clues as to why...**

I'm having trouble getting my tests to pass after changing the code as per listing 9.49 and 9.50. I have a feeling I'm missing a detail somewhere, but I can't seem to find it. Here is my code:

**edit.html.erb**
This page should render the shared 'fields', which has been refactored as part of the exercise.

```
    <% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
    <h1>Update your profile</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
                <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
                <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>

            <%= gravatar_for @user %>
            <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails" target="_blank">change</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**new.html.erb**
This page should render the shared 'fields', which has been refactored as part of the exercise.

```
    <% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
                <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
                <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**_fields.html.erb**
This page has been refactored. I have a feeling the error has something to do with this, but again I'm not sure.

```
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :passsword %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
```

**Here are the RSpec tests that keep failing:**

```
describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign Up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
end

describe "signup" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with valid information" do 
        before do 
            fill_in "Name",                  with: "Example User"
            fill_in "Email",                 with: "user@example.com"
            fill_in "Password",              with: "foobar"
            fill_in "Confirm Password",      with: "foobar"
        end

        it "should create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
        end

        describe "after saving the user" do
            before { click_button submit }
            let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }

            it { should have_link('Sign out') }
            it { should have_title(user.name) }
            it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
        end
    end
end

describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do 
        sign_in user
        visit edit_user_path(user)
    end

    describe "with valid information" do 
        let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
        let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
        before do 
            fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
            fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
            fill_in "Password",         with: user.password 
            fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
            click_button "Save changes"
        end

        it { should have_title(new_name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
        specify { expect(user.reload.name).to eq new_name }
        specify { expect(user.reload.email).to eq new_email }
    end
end
```

**Here are my failed tests:**

```
Failures:

1) UserPages signup with valid information should create a user
   Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
   count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:85:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) UserPages signup with valid information after saving the user 
   Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out') }
   expected #has_link?("Sign out") to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:92:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) UserPages signup with valid information after saving the user 
   Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
   expected #has_selector?("div.alert.alert-success", {:text=>"Welcome"}) to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:94:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) UserPages signup with valid information after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(user.name) }
     NoMethodError:
     undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:93:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

>  5) UserPages edit with valid information 
>     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
>       expected #has_selector?("div.alert.alert-success") to return true, got false
>     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:138:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
>
>  6) UserPages edit with valid information 
>     Failure/Error: specify { expect(user.reload.name).to eq new_name }
>       
>       expected: "New Name"
>            got: "Person 65"
>       
>       (compared using ==)
>     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:140:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
>
>  7) UserPages edit with valid information 
>     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(new_name) }
>       expected #has_title?("New Name") to return true, got false
>     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:137:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
>
>  8) UserPages edit with valid information 
>     Failure/Error: specify { expect(user.reload.email).to eq new_email }
>       
>       expected: "new@example.com"
>            got: "person_64@example.com"
>       
>       (compared using ==)
>     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:141:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
>
>Finished in 6.01 seconds
>88 examples, 8 failures
>
>Failed examples:
>
>rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:84 # UserPages signup with valid information should >create a user
>rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:93 # UserPages signup with valid information after >saving the user 
>rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:92 # UserPages signup with valid information after >saving the user 
>rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:94 # UserPages signup with valid information after >saving the user 
>rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:138 # UserPages edit with valid information 
>rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:140 # UserPages edit with valid information 
>rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:137 # UserPages edit with valid information 
>rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:141 # UserPages edit with valid information 
>
>Randomized with seed 6990
```

Comment: `Confirmation` != `Confirm Password`.

Comment: Updated with the suggested change, but it still doesn't pass. The only hint given by the returned failed test is that it's just not achieving the goal of the test. It doesn't seem to give any clues as to why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at your _fields.html.erb

Change `<%= f.label :passsword %>` to `<%= f.label :password %>` (emphasis on the number of S's in "password".)

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something small like that but I couldn't figure it out.